# Setting a custom @font in a <title> tag? Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want to create my custom font, having my logo as a symbol. And would set it for a `<title>` tag to display it in browsers.

— So, is it possible?
— Any tricks for it?

Thanks a lot for any help and ideas!

Comment: Are you trying to ask, if you can set a custom logo as the `<title>` tag in html?

Comment: Yes, but to set it as a font.

Comment: Please, read the question again.

Comment: I have read the question thank you, I am fairly sure you cannot put custom fonts within the `<title>`. It it just the browser default.

Comment: You cannot change the system font from within the browser. This would amount to a security risk

Comment: Why don't you just use a favicon? Place it inside your root directory. Are you asking for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the font in the title. Sadly the [W3C Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2) does not allow this.

The only thing I know, is to set a custom behavior on the `document.title` with javascript.

Here are two examples, but you have to try it in your own enviroment, because in this build in stackoverflow-interpreter `document.title` is not available.

```js
var titleText = " t i t l e ";
var pos = 0;
var blinkCount = 0;
var blink = [".....", ".. ..", ".   ."];
var doScrollingTimeout = null;
var doBlinkTimeout = null;

function DoScrolling() {
  clearTimeout(doBlinkTimeout);
  document.title = titleText.substring(pos, titleText.length) + blink[0] + titleText.substring(0, pos);
  pos++;
  if (pos > titleText.length) {
    pos = 0;
  }
  doScrollingTimeout = window.setTimeout("DoScrolling()", 150);
}

function DoBlink() {
  clearTimeout(doScrollingTimeout);
  document.title = blink[blinkCount % 3] + titleText.slice(0, blinkCount) + titleText.charAt(blinkCount).toUpperCase() + titleText.slice(blinkCount + 1, titleText.length - 1) + blink[blinkCount % 3];
  blinkCount++;
  if (blinkCount == titleText.length) {
    blinkCount = 0;
  }
  doBlinkTimeout = window.setTimeout("DoBlink()", 350);
}
DoScrolling();
```

Copy the javascript and HTML to a local file, because in the stackoverflow-interpreter `document.title` is not available

```
<button onclick="DoScrolling();">Scroll</button>
<button onclick="DoBlink()">Blink</button>
```